# How to convert Row to Columns in Linq

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have table ReportData having below records

| Agency | Year | Month | MonthCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | 2017 | Jan | 4 |
| One | 2017 | Feb | 6 |
| One | 2017 | Nov | 29 |
| One | 2017 | Dec | 38 |
| One | 2018 | Jan | 20 |
| One | 2019 | Feb | 18 |
| Two | 2017 | Jan | 24 |
| Two | 2017 | Feb | 66 |
| Three | 2017 | Nov | 9 |
| Four | 2017 | Dec | 8 |
| Four | 2018 | Jan | 22 |
| Four | 2019 | Feb | 48 |

how to convert into below table? please let me know the Linq statement. Thank you for your help in advance.

| Agency | Month | 2017 | 2018 | 2019 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | Jan | 4 | 20 | 0 |
| One | Feb | 6 | 0 | 18 |
| One | Nov | 29 | 0 | 0 |
| One | Dec | 38 | 0 | 0 |
| Two | Jan | 24 | 0 | 0 |
| Two | Feb | 66 | 0 | 0 |
| Three | Nov | 9 | 0 | 0 |
| Four | Jan | 0 | 22 | 0 |
| Four | Feb | 0 | 0 | 48 |
| Four | Dec | 8 | 0 | 0 |

source class structure

```
    public class ReportingData
{
    public string AgencyName { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string MonthNumnber { get; set; }
    public string Month { get; set; }
    public int MonthCount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I tried doing it using data table but now sure how to do it Linq. So asking question if anyone know how write Linq statement or point me to direction - Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your source and destination class structures?

Comment: @SateeshPagolu  here my source class  public class ReportingData
    {
        public string AgencyName { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public string MonthNumnber { get; set; }
        public string Month { get; set; }
        public int MonthCount { get; set; }
    }

Comment: @SateeshPagolu - I have added the source class to question for better reading

Comment: can you also add your destination type definition?

Comment: my destination type is dynamic i.e. distinct year should be transform to column. As I shown in above desire output. I am not sure how I put that in destination structure.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for Pivot Grid control? They are doing that automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that per [Agency, Month] combination, you want the MonthCounts of years 2017..2019.

I wonder what you want in a few years: only the last three years? or years 2017.. 2025? But that is a later problem.

My advice would be to make Groups of ReportData with same value of [Agency, Month] combination. Use the
[overload of Enumerable.GroupBy that has a parameter resultSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____2__)
to precisely define the result. If your data is in a different process (usually a database), use the IQueryable version.

```
IEnumerable<Report> reportData = ...

// make groups with same values for [Agency, Month] combination
var result = reportData.GroupBy(report => new
{
    Agency = report.Agency,
    Month = report.Month,
},

// parameter resultSelector: for every [Agency, Month] combination,
// and all reports that have this [Agency, Month] combination,
// make one new:
(agencyMonthCombination, reports] => new
{
    Agency = agencyMonthCombination.Agency,
    Month = agencyMonthCombination.Month,

    Year2017 = reports.Where(report => report.Year == 2017)
                      .Select(report => report.MonthCount)
                      .Sum();

    Year2018 = reports.Where(report => report.Year == 2018)
                      .Select(report => report.MonthCount)
                      .Sum();

    Year2019 = reports.Where(report => report.Year == 2018)
                      .Select(report => report.MonthCount)
                      .Sum();
```

If you expect only one report per year, you don't have to Sum, you can just use FirstOrDefault.

You see the disadvantage of this approach of naming the years 2017..2019. Code would be much easier if you made it for all years, or the last N years:

```
// parameter resultSelector
(agencyMonthCombination, reports] => new
{
    Agency = agencyMonthCombination.Agency,
    Month = agencyMonthCombination.Month,

    // group the reports with this [Agency, Month] combination in years
    MonthCounts = reports.GroupBy(report => report.Year,

        (year, reportsInThisYear) => new
        {
            Year = year,
            MonthCount = reportsInThisYear.Select(report => report.MonthCount).Sum(),
        })

        // if you only want the last N: orderby descending Year and Take(N)
        .OrderByDescending(yearMonthCount => yearMonthCount.Year)
        .Take(N)

        .ToList(),
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much Harald Coppoolse!  This is exactly what I was trying to do.